# Default value in Schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have `my_perfect_random` function that returns value of string

```
schema "something_greate" do
  field :my_amazing_field, :string, default: my_perfect_random
  timestamps()
end
```

the error is

```
undefined my_perfect_random/0
```

The function is written in the same module. I've tried to use `MyModule.my_perfect_random`, but got the same error

Pls help me to fix it

Comment: You cannot have a function call as the default value as the schema declaration is evaluated at compile time. You'll probably want to attach the default value in a changeset creation function.

Comment: Ok, thank u so much